# AngularJS evaluation of deferred objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, deferred

I have a simple app that returns objects from a REST API and binds them to a scope var.  This works OK, but if I try to do any work on the objects returned from the $resource promise, the objects are undefined.

I put together this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qBsiR0w8bgJ4fYA3jigC?p=info) to reproduce the behaviour using the $q service.  The first part binds a simple array to the scope, the second gets the same array via a deferred object.  The third gets the array via a deferred object again then tries to apply some simple logic to the returned object.  Unfortunately the returned object has no 'length' attribute.  Clearly I am missing something, presumably some usage of $scope.$apply but I've had no luck there either.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `then` with your promise.

```
asyncInit().then(function(data){
  $scope.deferredPersons = data;
});
```

From here on, you have access to your data per usual, and can call `.length` on it. Note, you should always handle errors when using promises, otherwise it can get hard to debug.

Comment: Thanks for that. Amended [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dmciBfIDW9X42pEtQ314?p=preview) now has rudimentary error handling and shows real work being done to the deferred object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use length, use `deferredPersons.then.length`

`if (deferredPersons.then.length > 0)`

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZmgaQJJeuCheQ6WVCMkQ?p=preview)